# How to validate the dynamically created form using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually I'm creating the form dynamically and i have done two way binding also. Now I want to do the validation.

**Requirements:**

- 1. If i have value in field for *(eg. Name: Raja)*. If edit that value using `$watch` or `$dirty` we can check that modified or not. The same thing I want to get reverse also. Suppose I edited the value Raja to Raj and later again i'm adding the 'a' means Raja. If i give previous value again the status `$dirty` i should get false.
- 2. How can do this thing for whole form rather than giving each and every field.

Please help me anyone on this.

Here is [my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5IPipFfSZmGGyGbrnXA?p=preview) for simple example.

Comment: You can write a `directive` and use it on each `input` of your form.

Comment: @Mistalis - can you please provide any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use something like `$setPristine()` 
http://plnkr.co/edit/1LJ5alREMhFXOqO8ZWbj?p=preview

Comment: I would like to ask you one more thing. here you're checking every field with changed value(newv) because you know the fields but my case dynamically we're creating the form I don't the field name. how can i do for that. Please help me.

Comment: it' maybe a little sally but since the two object are the same, and only valors change
`for (key in $scope.master)`
http://plnkr.co/edit/1LJ5alREMhFXOqO8ZWbj?p=preview